# highlighting phrase or words problem

Tags: regex, preg-replace

```
function highlight_phrase($str, $phrase, $class='highlight') 
{ 
     if ($str == '') 
     { 
         return ''; 
     } 

     if ($phrase != '') 
     { 
         return preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($phrase, '/').')/Ui', '<span class="'.$class.'">'."\\1".'</span>', $str); 
     }  
     return $str; 
}
```

above code is what i use to highlight phrases in a string. I have problem with following issues:

1. if phrase is new car it matches new car and new cars both in a string meaning it highlights new car of new cars but i need not highlight new cars.
2. I could check for space but what if phrase ends with ,.? or ! etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\b` pattern to match word boundaries, i.e. in your case `/\b(new car)\b/` will match

- "the **new car** is blue"
- "the **new car**."
- "**new car**"

but not

- "all the new cars".

Answer (score 0):

Add `(?!\w)` to the regex.  This will cause it to only match when the phrase is followed by a non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

```
return preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($phrase, '/')(?!\w)')/Ui', '<span class="'.$class.'">'."\\1".'</span>', $str);
```